# Training multiple Sequential models in a row slows down

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras/TensorFlow (GPU) to create a time series forecasting model. I have 100x of time series and want to train a network for each of them.

Running a few time series in a row is fine, but once I run 100x or 1000x then it appears that the training time of each model increase slowly (but surely). Is there a simple reason for this ?

Below is code to reproduce the issue (note that it could take a while to run).

https://gist.github.com/mannsi/c5666c4b786c35c3443beea6d13a32fe

On my machine the first iteration takes 10s, iteration #250 takes 16s and iteration #500 takes 25s.

I am new to Neural Networks and Keras/TF so maybe this is totally normal but I did not factor this in when doing my back-of-the-envelope time calculations.

System info:

- python 3.5
- keras (1.2.2)
- tensorflow-gpu(1.0.0)

EDIT: I tested the same code on a TensorFlow CPU backend and I see the exact same behavior there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that there is some overhead building up in the computation graph over each iteration. Use the Keras backend function `K.clear_session()` to reset the underlying Tensorflow session between each run.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your gpu warms up and therefore the power is lowered to reduce temperature?
How long does the first iteration take if you relaunch it after having done many iterations?

Comment: I will try this. Will run 250 iterations, kill the process and start it again.

Comment: Tried it and it immediately went back to 10s. The GPU temp is hovering around 60°

Answer (score 0):

As your model parameters didn't change, you have to compile only once the model. Then you can build a loop for fitting it.
You instantiate a model and compile it in every loop, that's why your memory consumption grows continuously.

Comment: @Mike Can't answer, as it has been removed.