# Why does this python code increase Google Colab RAM more than half?

Tags: python, split

Once I ran the split data method the Google Colab RAM increase more than half (my RAM is 12) I didn't even have enough RAM to run my model
my data size is around 5500-7000

```
seed_constant = 123
feature, feature_test, label_, label_test= train_test_split(ls_image,ls_labels,test_size=0.2,train_size=0.8)
feature_train, feature_val, class_train, class_val = train_test_split(feature,label,test_size = 0.25,train_size =0.75)
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly ?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Take a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54878446/memory-usage-is-close-to-the-limit-in-google-colab